# Beautiful Soup - having trouble on a specific page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've successfully been able to use beautiful soup in the past (I'm still learning how to use it), but I'm getting stuck on how to get this one specific table here:

https://fantasydata.com/nfl-stats/point-spreads-and-odds?season=2017&seasontype=1&week=1

In the past, it's as simple as doing:

```
url = 'https://fantasydata.com/nfl-stats/point-spreads-and-odds?   season=2017&seasontype=1&week=1' 
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
```

or

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
page_url = 'https://fantasydata.com/nfl-stats/point-spreads-and-odds?season=2017&seasontype=1&week=1' %(year,nfl_week)
driver.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
```

but none of the data in the table is there to be parse from the page source.

Is there a better way to handle this with beautiful soup?

EDIT:

Ok, so I went back and did:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
page_url = 'https://fantasydata.com/nfl-stats/point-spreads-and-odds?season=2017&seasontype=1&week=1' %(year,nfl_week)
driver.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
```

again. THIS time, the data was showing up. I assumed that since it was being loaded in, that using Selenium was the correct way to go, but got thrown off when it didn't work.

Any ideas on why that didn't work the first time? I didn't close the browser or anything before the page loaded.

Comment: The table being populated by javascripts after the page loads. What I have done in the past drive to the page then inject an API call with jQuery. I'm sure there are plenty of other options.

Comment: thanks. I actually was using selenium because I remember running into the issue of tables being populated after the page loads. I was running into trouble here because I did it like I normally would, but this time it wasn't working properly. I finally tried it additional times and it worked. I;m not sure where the original problem was then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need BeautifulSoup or Selenium for this. Data is available as python dictionary on `POSTing` query to `https://fantasydata.com/NFLTeamStats/Odds_Read`.

```
query = {  # just mimicking sample query that I saw after loading your link
    'page': 1,
    'pageSize': 50,
    'filters.season': 2017,
    'filters.seasontype': 1,
    'filters.week': 1,
}
response = requests.post('https://fantasydata.com/NFLTeamStats/Odds_Read', data=query)
data = response.json()
data
{'Data': [{'Date': 'September 7, 2017 8:30 PM', 'Favorite': 'at Patriots', 'PointSpread': '-9.0', 'UnderDog': 'Chiefs', 'OverUnder': '48.0', 'AwayTeamMoneyLine': '+400', 'HomeTeamMoneyLine': '-450'}, {'Date': 'September 10, 2017 1:00 PM', 'Favorite': 'Buccaneers', 'PointSpread': '-2.5', 'UnderDog': 'at Dolphins', 'OverUnder': '41.5', 'AwayTeamMoneyLine': '-140', 'HomeTeamMoneyLine': '+120'}, {'Date': 'September 10, 2017 1:00 PM', 'Favorite': 'at ...
```

You could find this method through studying network section of Chrome developer tools (push F12), especially XHR subsection:
[image: request data]
[image: request response]

Comment: If they have same-origin policy for http requests it will not be this straightforward to make API calls. That may not be the case for this API, but I have been to sites where it was easier to just use selenium than to try and mimic the options/headers/cookies needed to bypass the CORS block.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I did some snooping around, and someone beat me to it!!! I did the same thing as the other answer but in Firefox dev tools (the combination ctrl+shift+k), using the `xhr` section of the Network tab just like the other answer. It looks like the API call that populates the table on your site is a `POST` request to `https://fantasydata.com/NFLTeamStats/Odds_Read`. Here is a `js` object with all of the available parameters:

```
{
filter:,    
filters.endweek:,
filters.exportType:,
filters.leaguetype:,
filters.minimumsnaps:,
filters.playerid:,
filters.position:,
filters.scope:,
filters.scoringsystem:,
filters.searchtext:,
filters.season: 2017,
filters.seasontype: 1,
filters.startweek:,
filters.stattype:,
filters.subscope:,
filters.team:,
filters.teamaspect:,
filters.week: 1,
group:,
page: 1,
pageSize: 50,
sort:
}
```

The body of the `POST` will be a `json` object like the one above. If they don't block cross-origin requests, you can just use the Python requests library directly. If they do block cross-origin requests you can try to mimic the headers and options they set, or, I forget how, but I know you can inject a javascript AJAX request in selenium from the page. Just as a side note, you must use `webDriverWait` or some other async code to await the response if you want to automate async `js` inection in Python.